# Loading HTML document in DOM XML parser in VBScript fails if the <!DOCTYPE html> tag is present

Tags: xml, vbscript, xmldom

I am currently attempting to use VBScript to perform batch modifications to HTML files. To do this, I'm using the Microsoft.XMLDOM object. It is failing to load my HTML file as an XML document. After some experimenting, it appears that the following tag being at the first line is the culprit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If this line is removed, my script will work as expected. If this line is included, it will not load. No particular error message appears, but attempting to get anything out of the XMLDOM object will return nothing, which is the same behavior when the file the object attempts to load doesn't exist.

Does anyone know why this occurs and how to work around this? I cannot remove this tag from my files as they are HTML documents and they are routinely regenerated by another application.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
strFilePath = WScript.Arguments(0)
strTitlePrefix = WScript.Argument(1)

Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLDoc.Async = False

objXMLDoc.load(strFilePath)

Set objDoc = objXMLDoc.documentElement
Set objNodes = objDoc.selectNodes("//title")
For Each thisNode in objNodes
  OriginalTitle = thisNode.text
  NewTitle = TitlePrefix & OriginalTitle
  thisNode.text = NewTitle     
Next
```

It fails at this line:

```
Set objNodes = objDoc.selectNodes("//title")
```

This is the error message:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'objDoc'
```

The code does what I expect it to do if I remove the  tag at the top of the document it's trying to read, so I know that the problem is that this tag causes it to think the file is not an XML document.

Comment: `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is deprecated, use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` instead. For further help with your code: please show your code.

Comment: Please,[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51197272/edit) your question and add your code !

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I just tried my code loading the Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 object instead and unfortunately it made no difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you can narrow down the cause of the problem by adding some error checking after `load`:

```
objXMLDoc.load(strFilePath)
If objXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
   MsgBox "ERROR when loading " + strFileName + ": " + objXMLDoc.parseError.reason
End If
```

(Depending on your VBScript environment, you may have to use something else than `MsgBox`.)

You probably will get the error message

> error: DTD is prohibited.

The reason is that loading DTD syntax (such as `!DOCTYPE`) is prohibited by default in MSXML 6.0.
See [MSXML Security Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754611(v=vs.85)) for details. Here is the relevant part

> Some parts of XML (such as DTDs and inline schemas) are inherently risky. In the default installation configuration of MSXML 6.0, these features have been disabled. You are free to enable these features, but first you should ensure that the security risks associated with them do not apply to you.
>
> If you attempt to load a DTD without explicitly enabling ProhibitDTD Property, you will receive the following error:
>
> error: DTD is prohibited.

If you add the line

```
objXMLDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
```

before loading, the `DTD is probited` error will no longer occur.

You most probably also will have to add the line

```
objXMLDoc.validateOnParse = False
```

before loading, in case your HTML file does not contain the full HTML DTD (with it usually does not).

To summarize, here is the complete code:

```
strFilePath = "C:\Temp\test.html"

Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
objXMLDoc.Async = False
objXMLDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
objXMLDoc.validateOnParse = False
objXMLDoc.load(strFilePath)
If objXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
   MsgBox "ERROR when loading " + strFileName + ": " + objXMLDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set objDoc = objXMLDoc.documentElement

MsgBox TypeName(objDoc)
Set objNodes = objDoc.selectNodes("//title")
MsgBox objNodes.Length
```

It can successfully load and parse this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

The last line will output "1", as there is only one  tag.

Please note, that there is one drawback, however: *HTML is not XML!* 
I.e. not every HTML file is a well-formed XML file. 
E.g. if in the above sample HTML file, there would be a `<br>` tag (without matching `</br>`), loading would fail.
Only XML compliant HTML files can be opened using the above method.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Do you know where I could find a reference for the setProperty method and its available properties? I am using the following website, and it does not appear to have this information:
http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/xml_dom/home.html

Comment: Also, it is true that I'm taking a risk by processing HTML files with an XML parser. I'll look into making my own parsing logic, since the changes I want to script are very simple. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Bluewoods The properties are described in [Second-Level DOM Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766391(v%3dvs.85)).